# Regex: Individual list items within given tags

Tags: php, regex

I am wondering if there is a "one-regex-solution" for my current problem (in PHP):

Let's assume there are many files, which contain somewhere the following similar code scheme:

```
<p class="first-names">
Stan, Mary-Ann, William 3rd, Big Jim, Joe, Samantha
</p>
```

I want to match all first names within the files individually and I am wondering whether this can be done with one regular expression?

I tried so far the following, which gives me the complete list and the last two first first-names (`Joe`, `Samantha`), but not a complete list:

```
/(?<=<p class="first-names">)\W*(?:([a-zA-Z0-9\s-]{3,})+(?:, ))*(.*?)(?=[\W\ ]*<\/p>)/s
```

I am aware, that a two-step approach

a) get everything between the `<p>`-tags

b) split result from a)

This works but I am looking for something like

```
<Start_after_this_to_look_for_pattern> (?:(<Pattern>)<Separator>?){1 to many}<don't_look_after_this_for_pattern>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should not attempt to parse HTML with regex. Take a look at this question for information on available extensions. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: I did't see any `PHP` code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is, you can use the `\G` construct:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|<p[^>]*>\s*)
(?P<prename>(?:(?!</p>)[^,])+),?\s*
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/NkiWUW/1/).

---

As said a zillions times though, better use a parser with `xpath` queries instead and split the content on `,`.